# Getting request identifier in Mongoose 'pre' & 'post' hooks

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, metrics, mongoose-plugins

I am using Mongoose (latest version), Type script (NestJS).

I am working on collecting some metrics about our queries using 'pre' & 'post' hooks to measure the query time (including the network latency).
I have added a 'pre' hook that should start a timer that will be stopped in the 'post' hook.
The one thing that is missing is a unique identifier of each request, that I could set as a key in the 'pre' hook and identify the request in the 'post' hook using this key.

For some reason, it seems that there is no such an identifier on the request.

I was trying to set an identifier of my own using the [$locals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-$locals) field but it is undefined so it doesn't works.

Any ideas?

```
let count = 0;
UserSchema.pre(/.*/, async function () {
  this.$locals.requestId = count; // getting undefined error since locals doesn't exists

  console.log(`Pre - Request id: ${this.$locals.requestId}`);

  count += 1;
});

UserSchema.post(/.*/, function () {
  console.log(`Post - Request id: ${this.$locals.requestId}`);
});
```

Comment: Would you please share the part of your code to show how you're working with `$locals`?

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei

let count = 0;

// eslint-disable-next-line func-names
UserSchema.pre(/.*/, async function () {
  this.$locals.requestId = count;

  console.log(`Pre - Request id: ${this.$locals.requestId}`);

  count += 1;
});

// eslint-disable-next-line func-names
UserSchema.post(/.*/, function () {
  console.log(`Post - Request id: ${this.$locals.requestId}`);
});

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei I have added my code to the question

Comment: The code seems fine, I've used `$locals` before and I'm pretty sure the issue is not related to the mongoose. However, have you tried to take `next` from the `pre` callback function and execute it right after the `count` increments?

Comment: Can you share an example for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use with `next` parameter:

```js
let count = 0;
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.$locals.requestId = count;
  console.log(`Pre - Request id: ${this.$locals.requestId}`);
  count += 1;
  next();
})
```

Comment: Still not working, the 'next()' is not even taking place since I am getting "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'requestId')"

Comment: That means you do not even have the `$locals` in this context. Which version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: Exactly, this is why I can't understand what is going on! 
    "mongodb": "4.2.2",
    "mongoose": "6.1.2"